# How can I calculate the means of rows while excluding the zero values from rows in data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the mean of each row in my data frame. There are zeros in each row and I want to exclude these from calculation. I do not want to remove the entire row but only the zeros and calculate the mean of remaing values in each row. If row has all zero values than result should be Zero.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about

```
nzmean <- function(x) {
    if (all(x==0)) 0 else mean(x[x!=0])
}
apply(mydata,1,nzmean)
```

?

It occurs to me that it might be *marginally* faster to do

```
nzmean <- function(x) {
    zvals <- x==0
    if (all(zvals)) 0 else mean(x[!zvals])
}
```

i.e. try to avoid doing the comparison of `x` with zero twice.

Answer (score 15):

Or what you could do is assign `NA` to zero, which is effectively what you want to do. Some sample data:

```
spam = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
spam[1,2] = 0
spam[4,3] = 0
spam[10,] = 0
spam[spam == 0] <- NA
```

and use `rowMeans`, the `ifelse` is to check for rows that are entirely `NA`. The `na.rm` argument is important here:

```
mean_values = rowMeans(spam, na.rm = TRUE)
mean_values = ifelse(is.na(mean_values), 0, mean_values)
```

Comment: this is probably (?) faster than my solution for very large data sets.

Comment: I also like using NA conceptually, it makes it clear 0 is not a valid number.

Comment: This is a very clever approach and maybe faster than @BenBolker's.

Comment: I think I already said it was probably faster.  This approach does have two possible drawbacks: (1) it's clever (which is actually a *disadvantage* if it makes it harder to understand) (2) it modifies the original data, which could be inefficient if you want to do something else with the data in its original format.