# Grouping DataFrame and Averaging Rows in Multiple Columns Based on Groupings, Ignoring Zeros

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame `data` looks like the following:

```
Week  Group   Cost   Revenue
Wk1   A       104    148
Wk1   A       0      159
Wk1   A       92     151
Wk1   A       113    144
Wk1   B       331    500
WK1   B       325    524
Wk1   B       363    488
Wk1   B       0      497
Wk2   A       132    0
.
.
.
```

Here is the R code I used to get there from an unordered csv file:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- read.csv(...)
data <- tbl_df(d)
data <- arrange(data, Group, Week)
```

I need to average the values in the Cost and Revenue columns of my data frame based on which Group and Week they belong to.

So for example, I want the average Revenue and Cost for Group A in Week 1.

The resulting values would look something like (I'm not sure on the formatting, just showing what values I should get):

```
Week  Group   Avg Cost   Avg Revenue
Wk1   A       103        150.5
Wk1   B       339.6      502.25
.
.
.
```

**Question:**
How do I average my columns grouped by their Group and their Week such that I get the desired results above?  I want to use the `dplyr` package to do this.

**Issues:**
Some of my rows have zeros.  I don't want to average the zeros ( so not `(104 + 0 + 92 + 113)/4`  but rather ignore them so `(104 + 92 + 113)/3` ).  I cant simply `filter()` out the rows with zeros either, because often times only one of my Cost or Revenue columns has zeros not both.

I know I can average with `summarize()` using `mean()`, but not sure how to group the means the way I need and ignore zeros in the calculations.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason for you to WANT to use `dplyr` package?

Comment: its intuitive, functional (in the programming paradigm sense), and I am trying to learn it better.  I am open to other techniques though..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I'd add a *dplyr* answer.

First, you could do this within `summarise`, removing any 0 values from `Cost` and `Revenue` separately using the extract function (`[`).

```
require(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(Week, Group) %>%
    summarise(Cost = mean(Cost[Cost > 0]), Revenue = mean(Revenue[Revenue > 0]))
```

In terms of typing efficiency, `summarise_each` is another useful option in a case like this where you want to use the same function on multiple columns.  You can take advantage of the `.` coding to remove any 0 values from each of the numeric variables as you take the `mean`.

```
dat %>% group_by(Week, Group) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean(.[. > 0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `data.table` package. It is literally 100 time faster and more intuitive.

You can use `fread` function to read your csv files to data.tables. but here is just an example

```
DT = data.table(Week = c("wk1","wk2"),  Group = c("A","B","C","D"),   Cost = sample(1:49,30,replace=F),   Revenue = sample(1:49,10,replace=F))
#    Week Group Cost Revenue
# 1:  wk1     A   33      37
# 2:  wk2     B   17      28
# 3:  wk1     C   13       6
# 4:  wk2     D   39      25
# 5:  wk1     A   15       3
# 6:  wk2     B   34       8
# 7:  wk1     C    2      12
# 8:  wk2     D    9      11
# 9:  wk1     A   48      18
#10:  wk2     B   25      29
#11:  wk1     C   46      37
#12:  wk2     D   11      28
#13:  wk1     A   22       6
#14:  wk2     B    6      25
#15:  wk1     C   26       3
#16:  wk2     D   40       8
#17:  wk1     A   27      12
#18:  wk2     B   23      11
#19:  wk1     C   43      18
#20:  wk2     D   24      29
#21:  wk1     A   21      37
#22:  wk2     B   29      28
#23:  wk1     C   31       6
#24:  wk2     D    8      25
#25:  wk1     A   36       3
#26:  wk2     B    5       8
#27:  wk1     C    1      12
#28:  wk2     D   19      11
#29:  wk1     A    4      18
#30:  wk2     B   44      29
#    Week Group Cost Revenue
```

in the following line you should define which columns is used for grouping ; here I use `c("Week", "Group")`

```
DT[,list(Avg_Cost = mean(Cost),Avg_Revenue = mean(Revenue)),by = c("Week", "Group")]
```

[image]

look data table package manual for more info: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html

In order to **neglect zeros** in your `mean` function you can replace it with `nzmean`. Refer to this post: [How can I calculate the means of rows while excluding the zero values from rows in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583569/how-can-i-calculate-the-means-of-rows-while-excluding-the-zero-values-from-rows)

```
nzmean <- function(x) {
   zvals <- x==0
   if (all(zvals)) 0 else mean(x[!zvals])
}
```

so the answer would be:

```
DT[,list(Avg_Cost = nzmean(Cost),Avg_Revenue = nzmean(Revenue)),by = c("Week", "Group")]
```

Comment: I like the approach, but what if there are some 0s in the Cost or Revenue columns?  I need to ignore the 0s in the mean function.

Comment: you can replace `mean` with defined functions. look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583569/how-can-i-calculate-the-means-of-rows-while-excluding-the-zero-values-from-rows

Comment: replace `mean` with `nzmean`, where 
`nzmean <- function(x) {
    zvals <- x==0
    if (all(zvals)) 0 else mean(x[!zvals])
}`

Comment: A good answer @MahdiJadaliha but you make two statements without proof: that data.table is "is literally 100 time faster and more intuitive". If you're interested in convincing us that it's faster, the least you could do is link to another post as evidence. And when it comes to intuitiveness, well, I'll be the judge of that :-)

Comment: @BarkleyBG, still datatable is the fastest (100 times might be exaggeration in most of the cases) . here is the link for performance benchmark: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-:-Grouping

Answer (score 0):

A solution without any additional packages:

```
# Define a non-zero means function
nzmean <- function(x) {
  zvals <- x==0
  if (all(zvals)) 0 else mean(x[!zvals])
}
```

Then use `tapply`, considering a data.frame called `df`

```
tapply(df$Cost,list(df$Week,df$Group),nzmean )
```